# Как вывести массив в обратном порядке на Си?

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, вывод

из библиотек можно использовать только stdio.h

Answer (score 2):

```
const int size = 5;
int arr[size] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("%3d", arr[size - i-1]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `size` как отдельная переменная не нужна. Можно же подсчитать. `#define ASZ(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))`.

Comment: И второй вариант (когда `i` лишняя, да и вообще много букв в оригинале) `size_t size = ASZ(a); while (size--) printf(..., a[size]);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int i = 5; i > 0; --i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Смотри комментарии к другому ответу.